# Can't enable no-console using eslint cli

Tags: eslint, vue-cli

I'm using eslint, and in my configuration file I have `"no-console": "off"`.

I want to turn it on for my CI system, so I've been using the command line (vue cli syntax):

`vue-cli-service lint --rule '"no-console": "error"'`

This doesn't work.

However, if I invert things (set `error` in the configuration, and pass `off` as a flag) it does work.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: it should probably look like `vue-cli-service --rule 'no-console: 2'`
PS: `"error"` may be working too I guess.

---

You can make a config in a lot of places but the usual one is probably `.eslintrc.js` in which you can write

```js
module.exports = {
  [...]

  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {
    "no-console": "off",
  },
}
```

As shown here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console
This one should work but it always depend on how your project is setup too.

Comment: Yep, that's what I have. My question is -- How do I selectively turn on 'no-console' using command line flags?

Comment: You pretty much got the syntax: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#-rule With a reminder on the rule numbers available here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#configuring-rules